# d3.js svg scale transformation

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to append a "block" to an existing svg and apply a transformation to this added "block".

This is my test code. I used a button to trigger the event:

```
    $("#insert_prodotto_daxml").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "assets/materiale/singolo_CLOUD_inkMATTEO.svg",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                var svg = d3.select("svg");

                var blocksect = d3.select("svg").append('defs');
                // provo ad aggiungere dinamicamente la definizione da stringa xml
                var newblock = blocksect.append("g").attr("id", "block01");
                newblock.html(data);
                //svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(30,50)").append("use").attr("xlink:href","#block01").on("click", handleClickBlock)
                //svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(0, -100) scale(3)").append("use").attr("xlink:href","#block01").on("click", handleClickBlock)
                svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(0, 0) scale(1,1)").append("use").attr("xlink:href","#block01").on("click", handleClickBlock)
                svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(100, 30) scale(1.5)").append("use").attr("xlink:href","#block01").on("click", handleClickBlock)
            }
        });
    });
```

The previous code works fine, but if I try to mirror the element changing at least one scale factor to negative, it does not show the element:

```
svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(0, 0) scale(1,-1)").append("use").attr("xlink:href","#block01").on("click", handleClickBlock)
```

Are perhaps negative values unsupported?

Kind regards,
Matt

Comment: If you flip it like that and don't have your viewBox set up other than you your snippet shows, doing `scale(1, -1)` will flip it around the x-axis to an area where it won't get displayed. Try doing something like `scale(1, -1) translate(0, 100)` or some other value to move the flipped element back into the visible viewport. Alternatively, depending on your needs, you may adjust your viewBox to also include the negative coordinate values.

Comment: Hi @altocumulus, it worked using translate()!